# Using Python Selenium to download a file in memory, not in disk

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a bunch of scripts that do web scraping, download files, and read them with pandas. This process has to be deployed in a new architecture where download the files on disk is not appropriate, instead is preferable to save the file in memory and read it with pandas from there. For demonstration purposes I leave here a web scraping script that downloads an excel file from a random website:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


pathDriver = #Path to chromedriver

driver  = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=pathDriver)

url = 'https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-xls-download/'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

file_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-files"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a[1]')
file_link.click()
```

This script effectively downloads the file in my Downloads folder. What I've tried is to put a `StringIO()` or `BytesIO()` stream before and after the `click()` method and read the object similiar to this:

```
file_object = StringIO()
df = pd.read_excel(file_object.read())
```

But the file_object doesn't capture the file and even the file is still downloaded in my disk.

Any suggestions with that?

Comment: Instead of `file_link.click()` can you find what is the `href` of the link? That way you can do `df = pd.read_excel(href)` or download it to a temp folder / memory with `requests`

Comment: Hi @CodeDifferent, unfortunately, the "href" attribute is not present in all Html elements that I have in my scrapper's scripts, so is not a scalable solution.

Comment: @DavidLópez please provide another use case where the "href" attribute isn't present.

Comment: either create a ramdisk or use a script injection to intercept the request/response.

Comment: Scraping is the word that better fits the context of this question. Note that scrapping and scraping have significantly [different meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842376/14349691). Would have edited the question myself, but apparently there is a requirement on edits having to change at least 6 characters.

Answer (score 8):

Your question can be accomplished by adding the *selenium add_experimental_option*.
I also redesigned your code to loop through the table to extract the href to pass them to StringIO. No files are downloaded to my local system using this code.

If I missed something please let me know.

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from io import StringIO
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

prefs = {
    'profile.default_content_setting_values':
     {
        'automatic_downloads': 0
  },

      'profile.content_settings.exceptions':
    {
        'automatic_downloads': 0
    }
  }

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url_main = 'https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-xls-download/'

driver.get(url_main)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-files"]//td/a')
for element in elements:
   if str(element.get_attribute("href")).endswith('.xls'):
     file_object = StringIO(element.get_attribute("href"))
      xls_file = file_object.read()
      df = pd.read_excel(xls_file)
      print(df.to_string(index=False))

        First Name  Last Name  Gender        Country  Age        Date    Id
      1      Dulce      Abril  Female  United States   32  15/10/2017  1562
      2       Mara  Hashimoto  Female  Great Britain   25  16/08/2016  1582
      3     Philip       Gent    Male         France   36  21/05/2015  2587
      4   Kathleen     Hanner  Female  United States   25  15/10/2017  3549
      5    Nereida    Magwood  Female  United States   58  16/08/2016  2468
      6     Gaston      Brumm    Male  United States   24  21/05/2015  2554
      7       Etta       Hurn  Female  Great Britain   56  15/10/2017  3598
      8    Earlean     Melgar  Female  United States   27  16/08/2016  2456
      9   Vincenza    Weiland  Female  United States   40  21/05/2015  6548
      
      sleep(360)
```

Here is an example using a RAMDISK that was mentioned in the comments. This option does not use *selenium add_experimental_option* or StringIO.

```
import fs
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url_main = 'https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-xls-download/'

driver.get(url_main)

urls_to_process = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="table-files"]//td/a')

# Create RAMDISK
mem_fs = fs.open_fs('mem://')
mem_fs.makedir('hidden_dir')

for element in elements:
  if str(element.get_attribute("href")).endswith('.xls'):
     with mem_fs.open('hidden_dir/file1.csv', 'w') as in_file:
        in_file.write(element.get_attribute("href"))
        in_file.close()
     with mem_fs.open('hidden_dir/file1.csv', 'r') as out_file:
        df = pd.read_excel(out_file.read())
        print(df.to_string(index=False))
        # same output as above
        sleep(360)
```

Comment: Hi, @Life is complex. The solution you provide works fine for the example I gave, but unfortunately, as I explained above, I have to scrape a lot of webs, and most of them don't have the "href" element in the button that downloads the desired file, so this solution doesn't scale well. I'm searching for a way to obtain the URL or endpoint that the button "actives". Is like the "href" element were hidden, so If I achieve to find this I could applied the approach you suggested to all my scrappers: file_object = StringIO(my_desired url)

Comment: @DavidLópez You need to provide other use cases, because I can only develop an answer from the question and its data elements.  Without these additional data elements  I don't know how my answer scales across multiple websites.

Comment: can you create this RAMDISK and then set that as your download directory? Using download.default_directory?

Comment: @DMart that is what is happening in the RAMDISK answer.  I'm creating a disk in memory and writing and reading from the disk.

Comment: sorry, i didn't see in your code where you set the download directory.

Comment: @DMart here is the documentation on the module - https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex is there a way to, for example, download the file and save in this RAMDISK? I'm am thinking in create the RAMDISK and tell chrome driver to save the file in this location

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a few extra lines of code.  Do you need me to update the answer?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex that would be great!

Comment: @DavidLópez this answer that I wrote has the details on using RAMDISK,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638010/compare-csv-files-content-with-filecmp-and-ignore-metadata/64763745#64763745

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex will appreciate if you check on this question that has to download a file without a file link. 

[ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71080967/python-selenium-to-download-file-to-memory ]

Answer (score 2):

IMO, using selenium is clearly unnecessary.Only using `requests + beautifulsoup + pandas` is okay.(this would much faster than using selenium,and need less code).

Code below:

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-xls-download/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
# get the download link
file_link = soup.select_one(".file-link > a").get("href")

# download it in memory
bytes_of_file = requests.get(file_link).content
df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(bytes_of_file))
print(df)
```

Result:

```
   0 First Name  Last Name  Gender        Country  Age        Date    Id
0  1      Dulce      Abril  Female  United States   32  15/10/2017  1562
1  2       Mara  Hashimoto  Female  Great Britain   25  16/08/2016  1582
2  3     Philip       Gent    Male         France   36  21/05/2015  2587
3  4   Kathleen     Hanner  Female  United States   25  15/10/2017  3549
4  5    Nereida    Magwood  Female  United States   58  16/08/2016  2468
5  6     Gaston      Brumm    Male  United States   24  21/05/2015  2554
6  7       Etta       Hurn  Female  Great Britain   56  15/10/2017  3598
7  8    Earlean     Melgar  Female  United States   27  16/08/2016  2456
8  9   Vincenza    Weiland  Female  United States   40  21/05/2015  6548
```

And this wouldn't download any excel files.

Comment: Except if you are trying to download something behind services like Cloudflare, which blocks python scripts, curl, nodeJS, and many more.

Comment: There are just some legacy websites that don't have any link to any excel file and the only way to download the file is by clicking the button.